# Lower case column values in Sequelize (mysql) - Node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
let industryObject = await Industry.findOne({ where: { 'name': req.body.industry } });
```

I want to compare by keeping the lower case value of the `name` column, how can I do that using sequelize?
I am looking to achieve this.

```
select * from industry where lower(name) = 'small_case_industry_name';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Advanced queries with functions](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#advanced-queries-with-functions--not-just-columns-).

E.g.

```
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import Sequelize, { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

class Industry extends Model {}
Industry.init(
  {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  { sequelize, tableName: 'industries' },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await Industry.bulkCreate([{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'A' }]);
    // test
    const data = await Industry.findOne({
      where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('name')), 'a'),
      raw: true,
    });
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution result:

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "industries" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "industries" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "industries" ("id"   SERIAL , "name" VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'industries' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "industries" ("id","name") VALUES (DEFAULT,'a'),(DEFAULT,'A') RETURNING *;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "name" FROM "industries" AS "Industry" WHERE lower("name") = 'a' LIMIT 1;
{ id: 1, name: 'a' }
```

Check the data records in the database:

[image]